# iOS 15 - Background Sound - How Does the Timer Stay On With the Display Turned Off?

Tags: ios

I want to fall asleep using the **Background Sound** (not music) that debuted in iOS 15. Unlike the native Music and Podcasts apps - the timer cannot keep running once the display is turned off.

This seems counterintuitive.  I want to turn off the screen so that I can fall asleep - but if I set the timer so that the Background Sound switches off after a set time, everything stops playing when I manually turn off the screen.

Am I doing something wrong?  **Changing the setting in Accessibility so that 'Stop Sounds When Locked' is off does not fix the issue.**

Comment: Isn’t the point of background sounds is that it stays low until you wake? This seems like an intentional feature as opposed to a bug. (P.S. this is my favorite HomePod mini feature of all time)

Comment: I guess that's another application for it.  But I don't want to use it that way.  I want it to help me fall asleep and the timer should be allowed to shut off the device  (even with the display off) - or I will wake with major battery drain.  This is how iOS handles the Music and Podcast apps - why is the Backgound Sound set up differently?

Comment: You certainly would want this for when there’s a charge present. Why Apple did this, we can only guess..